# Как установить серверную ubuntu на mac в качестве виртуальной ОС?

Tags: ubuntu, macos, virtual

Имеется ввиду следующее: как установить ubuntu, чтобы можно было из основной ОС(macOS) подключаться к ubuntu не прибегая к графическому отображению? Как будто ubuntu где-то далеко на чьем-то сервере и я к ней подключаюсь по ssh, т.е. не стандартный способ с помощью virtualBox.

Comment: Да, собственно, так же как и любую другую систему... тут наверно вопрос скорее "как организовать виртуальную сеть". Если речь о virtualbox, то ставите ubuntu (можно любую), в настройках виртуальной машины virtualbox в сети указываете тип подключения - NAT (можно bribge, например, но лично я nat использую) и ниже активируется "Проброс портов" - всё что Вам нужно сделать чтоб получить доступ по ssh, это указать порт хоста и порт гостя 22. Затем убедитесь что запущен sshd в ubuntu и можете из macos с помощью `ssh localhost` попробовать попасть внутрь ubuntu :)

Comment: @nobody ну, не совсем так, она должна быть запущена как бы без окна, только в консольном варианте или как фоновый процесс в macos

Comment: а в чём проблема запустить машину в фоновом режиме?

Comment: `vboxmanage startvm {"vmname" or UUID} --type headless` - я об этом, если что. Не подходит? Подробнее о headless режиме: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

Comment: @nobody да вроде то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить о запуске виртуальных машин "без окна" в фоновом режиме в контексте virtualbox, то можно это сделать либо жмякнув по имени виртуальной машины и далее "Запустить -> Запустить в фоновом режиме", либо сделать это через консоль:

```
vboxmanage startvm {"vmname" or UUID} --type headless
```

Это называется headless режим и прочитать о нём можно [тут](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html).